# Re-execute powershell script on some condition after conversion to EXE

Tags: powershell

I have a script that I converted to EXE so I can run it as a service. I am trying to make the script execute itself again on some condition. I have a for loop in the script and I want to break and re-execute so it would similar to this:

```vb
foreach{
   if(Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd" != $CURRENTDATE){
          **re-execute script**
   }
   send_email($_)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code into function and in `if` call this function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

You can make a function, and call it directly:

```
function myFunction($myCollection)
foreach{
   if(Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd" != $CURRENTDATE){
          myFunction $myCollection)
   }
   send_email($_)
}
```

More info for using functions [can be found here](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-functions.html) (They are odd things compared to C syntax)

Would probably be the optimal route.

Another route would be a while loop:

```
while(Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd" != $CURRENTDATE)
{
   foreach{
          #Iterate foreach here, then exits to loop, where it checks condition again
            #If still does not match todays date, it goes through foreach loop again.
   }
} #loop
   send_email($_) #Script will not get here until it meets your date check condition
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this as a service you need some way to limit the frequency that the script checks the date, otherwise it'll use a lot of CPU!

There are a couple of ways you could do this. You could take other answers here and add the Start-Sleep cmdlet with a suitable amount of time in the for/while loop.

However I'm thinking you might have a reason to rerun your EXE. The other answers wouldn't rerun the EXE, they would just keep the EXE running until the date rolled around.

If you do want to rerun your EXE you can just enter the EXE's command line where you have **re-execute script**. You won't need the for loop, but you do need to invoke Start-Sleep to something reasonable.